# how to get information of an object instance from ID number

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, instance, tableview

I have a program that has 2 tables on two different windows. One table holds the customer name and id number and the other one hold the item name and number. They are both stored in a array and also in a .plist file.

What i would like to do is that on a third page there is going to be a sales page where the user will enter the customer id and item id and the program should be able to find the name and display it to a label. I don't know where to start and go. Could somebody please help or show me how to do i? I can upload any code that anybody wants to see but as I dont know where to start I dont know what to upload.
this is the customer.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString *name;
int memberNumber;


@interface Customer : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
NSString *name;
int memberNumber;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property int memberNumber;


@end
```

this is the customer.m

```
#import "Customer.h"

@implementation Customer

@synthesize name;
@synthesize memberNumber;


-(id) init
{
self = [super init];
if(self) 
    {
    name = @"Test";
    int i = arc4random()%1000000000000000000;
    if (i<0) 
        {
        memberNumber = i*-1;
        }
    else
        memberNumber = i;
}
return self;

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
if (self = [super init]) 
{
    self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    self.memberNumber = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"memberNumber"];


}
return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
[encoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[encoder encodeInt:memberNumber forKey:@"memberNumber"];

}

-(void)dealloc
{
[name release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

this is the tableView.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
NSString *filepath; 
@interface tableViewData : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> 
{
@private
    IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    NSString *filepath; 




}
-(IBAction)add:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender;





@end
```

this is the tableView.m file

```
#import "tableViewData.h"
#import "Customer.h"
@implementation tableViewData

-(void)awakeFromNib{
filepath = @"/Users/Desktop/CustomerNames.plist";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filepath]) 
{
    NSMutableArray *archive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filepath];
    list = archive;
}
else
    list=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
return [list count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
Customer *Customer = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
return [Customer valueForKey:identifier];
}

-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:     (NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
Customer *Customer = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
[Customer setValue:object forKey:identifier];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:list];
[data writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
}



-(IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
[list addObject:[[Customer alloc]init]];
[tableView reloadData];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:list];
[data writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
for (id name in list)
    NSLog(@"obj: %@", name);
NSLog (@"array:%@",list);


}


-(IBAction)remove:(id)sender
{
NSInteger row = [tableView selectedRow];
if (row != -1) 
{
    [list removeObjectAtIndex:row];
}

[tableView reloadData];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:list];
[data writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

}




-(void)dealloc
{
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

hope this helps

(xcode 4.2.1 for OS X)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if([myNumber isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    //do something here
}
```

That check if object myNumber is a NSNumber class Object. You can use whatever class you want of course. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

Comment: so if i understand correctly to get my program to display a name of a customer with just an ID number i would do what u said and then in the method bit i would say [label setValue name]; ?

Comment: Wait... what you mean by id? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html object identifiers or your internat customer ID?

Comment: i mean an ID number which has been given to each customer

Comment: Sorry, we misunderstood. So pass the row beetween view. @mhunturk give you the answer.

Comment: sorry but i am a complete beginner so im am not sure what i have to do. do i make a new object and class and then link them. what do i link to the interface. i am going to put the customer class code and also the table data source code so that you can see what i am trying to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If items you loaded to table are at the same order in your table you can use

```
    [myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

Then use can use the variables of the array that you needed.

Comment: sorry but i am a complete beginner so im am not sure what i have to do. do i make a new object and class and then link them. what do i link to the interface. i am going to put the customer class code and also the table data source code so that you can see what i am trying to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First in that code:

```
   -(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:                   (NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
          {
   Customer *Customer = [list objectAtIndex:row];
   NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
   [Customer setValue:object forKey:identifier];
   NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:list];
   [data writeToFile:filepath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
   }
```

change Customer *Customer to Customer *customer ALWAYS use that way.

Then use that method to understand which row is selected.In your case which customer is selected. I understand from your code that every row has a costumer and those customers are in your list array.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      //with this code you can get the selected customer from your list,
      Customer *customer=[list objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    }
```

Then you can reach the values of the customer.

Comment: hi. thanks for the answer. however when i do what u try i get 2 errors. one is :Instance method '-row' not found (return type defaults to 'id') and the other one is: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long'). also once i have done this how do i print the name of the customer depending of their IDnumber (memberNumber). another this thank you for tell me that i should do Customer*customer but if u dont mind my asking but why do u do this? is it just convention?thanks

Comment: thin about that you want to get the customer memberId. ın my case code will be     customer.memberId but in your casa Customer.memberId which will cause an error. It can act like a singleton class.you cant get the right value. Also try to change [indexPath row] to indexPath.row

Comment: is this an answer for iOS or OS X as i think UITableView is for iOS